# Is this function test possible?

Tags: php

I have some code I am trying with some compound conditional function testing. I keep encountering syntax errors & I believe it may not be possible. Does anyone know better? The snippet of code is below:

```
function getPayrollHoursBalance( $userId )
{
    if ( $userId )
       { ... preform a query which reports a pay grade ...}
        return $payGrade;
        }
    if ( $payGrade = 'A' || $payGrade = 'B' )
           { ... return a multiplier apply to a base salary ... }
        else
           {
           return 'FAIL, no userId!';
           }
      else
          { return 'FAIL, HOURS NEGATED!'; 
          }
}
```

From the error statements, I am producing errors at the point where the logical OR is being made, `if ( $payGrade = 'A' || $payGrade = 'B' )`

Can a logical operation be made within the conditional test to test determine if the function can be run? Or should I run another function which will have produced the 'T/F' state before the function is called?

I can't find much written about conditional function statements & nothing about running a logical test within the 'if (test) function.

I am sort of leaning towards an SQL JOIN within the query & take the multiple test, if & conditional out of the function & let SQL do the heavy lifting.

Thank you for your time to ponder this.

Comment: the code you provided doesn't make any sense... too many syntax mistakes..

Comment: I'm guessing (one of) your problem(s) is that you have an `if..else..else`, which doesn't make sense. You probably want `if { if..else } else`. Start by indenting and balancing your braces correctly so you'll see the issue.

Answer (score 2):

With this if-condition, you'll always get a `true`.

```
if ( $payGrade = 'A' || $payGrade = 'B' )
```

Here, you first **assign** the value `A` to the variable $payGrade. This assignment will return `true`, if it succeeded. You don't check, because you used a single `=`.

Edit your condition with double-`=`:

```
if ( $payGrade == 'A' || $payGrade == 'B' )
```

Comment: This is correct ^, what he's saying is `==` compares values, while `=` assigns. On an unrelated note, the OP would be better off running a compare against `in_array()` -> `if(in_array($payGrade, array('A', 'B'))) {...`, making it more readable.